# Nginx 502 error with localhost vs 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx

I have a web-application running on 127.0.0.1:8080. Initially I configured my `nginx.conf` by using `localhost:8080`. Example:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

This worked fine 99% of the time. The problem however was, that when a user made a request which triggered a panic in my web-application not only would that user get a 502-error, but my whole website would be down for ALL users. Until I restarted the web-application manually.

The expected behavior was that the user triggering the error would get a 502-error but it would be isolated for all other users. So the site would be still accessible instead of down for everyone.

I was stuck for a long time on how to fix this. Until I started using `127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `localhost:8080`. So

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

With using `127.0.0.1:8080` my site would not longer be down for everyone if one user triggered a panic in my web-application.

What is the reason for this? I thought `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` were the same. Is this because by using `localhost` the server still needs to do a DNS-request and the DNS is somehow unavailable due the error?

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is, but `localhost` can also be `::1`

Comment: ....and the FIRST thing to check is whether the 502 is originating on nginx or the origin server. Quoting the exact text appearing in the nginx logs here would also be de rigeur.